# Find all $m,n$ such that $mn|n^2+m^2+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$n$ and $m$ are positive integers. Find all values of division from $\dfrac{n^2+m^2+1}{nm}$ if $n^2+m^2+1$ is divisible by $nm$.

Every suggestion is desired. Thanks.

Comment: If $mn|n^2+m^2+1$, then $mn|m^2n^2+n^2+m^2+1$, i.e. $mn|(n^2+1)(m^2+1)$.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You can use this formula.   http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/101140

Answer (score 1):

the ratio can only be $3$ if an integer, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping#Example_2

As far as the actual pairs of numbers, we are solving
$$  m^2 - 3 m n + n^2 = -1,  $$
and the solutions (with $m \neq n$) are consecutive odd-index Fibonacci numbers,
$$ (1,1),   $$
$$ (2,1),   $$
$$ (5,2), $$ 
$$ (13,5), $$
$$ (34,13), $$
$$ (89,34), $$
where we can also switch $(m,n)$ to $(n,m).$ If we already have a solution $(x,y)$ with $x \geq y > 0,$ the next solution is
$$ (3x-y,x) $$